# How to mock a method call with Mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

i am trying to write Unittests for a MAS. Therefore i have to mock the agent an agent is communicating with. Here is an example of what i am trying to do at the moment. I have an agent A which is the one that i want to test. He calls B.method(arg) on an other agent B, which is mocked in my case. Normally B would call A.method(arg1, arg2, arg3). I am new to Mockito and doesn't know a lot about its possibilities. Is it possible to do something like when(mock.method).thenCall(A.method)?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: It doesn't look like you are really clear about what you want to test. Do you mean to check that when you invoke B, A is actually invoked as well?

Comment: You shouldn't do it, it's a bad design to ENFORCE `B` to call `A` (It is fine to do it, but enforcing it is wrong), the fact that `B` is calling `A` should be test in `B`'s unitests, not `A`'s.

Comment: It's certainly possible, using the `Answer` feature of Mockito.  Check the documentation.  However, this kind of circular dependency between two classes is almost certainly indicative of poor design.  I suggest you rethink the way the classes relate to each other.  And if nobody else posts an answer using the `Answer` feature, I'll do it later.

Comment: I know that you should not do this. But i didn't write the program, i only have to write tests for it. And as far as i know there were somme issues which caused this style of communication.

Answer (score 1):

A little late to the party, but I believe would be able to achieve what you wanted with an Answer.

The following will call a real method (methodOnA), whenever the mock method (methodOnB) is called:

```
doAnswer(new Answer<Void>() {
    @Override
    public Void answer(InvocationOnMock invocationOnMock) throws Throwable {
        realObjectA.methodOnA()
        return null;
    }
}).when(mockObjectB).methodOnB();
```

Answer (score 0):

The intent of mocking a method call is to immediately return a value (or throw an exception) when the method is called on the mock instance. It allows you to exercise the class-under-test without calling upon that class' collaborators.

So rather than delegate the method call to another method call, you would usually just `thenResult(someValue)` or `thenThrow(someException)`.

It may be that your test relies on a helper method to derive `someValue`, but that's unlikely to be a useful test.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't do it, it's a bad design to ENFORCE `B` to call `A` (It is fine to do it, but enforcing it is wrong), the fact that `B` is calling `A` should be tested in `B`'s unitests, not `A`'s, and `A` should be unaware of it.

You can on the other hand, verify with Mockito that `B.method()` was invoked (and how many times, and with which argument), or alternatively return a stub value from `B.method()` without invoking `A`, which is a good unitest - since it checks for a single behavior of `A`. (The call to `A.method()` should be tested seperately).

For example, returning a stub value with Mockito is easily done with

```
Mockito.when(mockedB.method(SOME_ARG_HERE)).thenReturn(SOME_RESULT);
```

Much more useful examples and information can be found at [Mockito's javadocs](http://mockito.googlecode.com/svn/branches/1.6/javadoc/org/mockito/Mockito.html)